# why mathjax in vue.js 3 Requires refresh on initial display developpement page and not work in step 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mathjax

I need to display in two successive steps the same expressions one under the other on the same page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzuPw.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5eOW.png)
with a button that increments a counter (etape)

During development, the display is updated in real time but certain expressions are only interpreted after a refresh of the browser page.
Also, in the second step, the mathematical expressions are not interpreted.
I remain puzzled.

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueMathjax from 'vue-mathjax-next';

createApp(App).use(VueMathjax).mount('#app')
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>Étape = {{ etape }}</h1>
        <h2> Requires page refresh even on initial display </h2>
        <div v-if="etape >= 0">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h3>(E 1) </h3> $$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}. $$
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3>(E 2) </h3> \( f(x) = x^2 + 2 x=2 \)
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3>(E 3) </h3> \( P_A(B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{ P(A)} \)
                </li>
            </ul>
            <h2> But the following two scriptures are not interpreted </h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h3>(E 4) </h3> $ f(x) = x^2 + 2 \quad \mathrm { if } \quad x=2 $
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3>(E 5) </h3> $ P_A(B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{ P(A)} $
                </li>
            </ul>
            <br />
            <button @click="etape++"> Presss Next step</button>
        </div>
        <div v-if="etape >= 1">
            <hr>
            <h2> second step : Étape = {{ etape }} </h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h3>(E 1) </h3> $$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}. $$
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3>(E 2) </h3> \( f(x) = x^2 + 2 x=2 \)
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3>(E 3) </h3> \( P_A(B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{ P(A)} \)
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h3>(E 4) </h3> $ f(x) = x^2 + 2 \quad \mathrm { if } \quad x=2 $
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3>(E 5) </h3> $ P_A(B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{ P(A)} $
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>




</template>

<script>
export default {
    components: {
    },
    data() {
        return {
            etape: 0,
        }
    }
};

</script>
<style>
</style>
```

a few fruitless hours. Reduced to a few lines to circumscribe the problem

Comment: view in Sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-mathjax-demo-forked-1u9hyi?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: View in action : http://mathilde.dhenin.fr/wp-content/uploads/dhenin/dist/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around :

Apps.vue :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Étape = {{ etape }}</h1>
    <h2>
      With vscode, change src, requires page refresh even on initial display
    </h2>
    <div v-if="etape >= 0">
      <ul>
        <li>(E 1) <vue-mathjax :formula="racine" /></li>
      </ul>
      <br />
      <button @click="etape++">Presss Next step</button>
    </div>
    <div v-if="etape >= 1">
      <hr />
      <h2>second step : Étape = {{ etape }}</h2>

      <textarea v-model="proba" />
      <br />
      whith input : <vue-mathjax :formula="proba" /> <br />
      without input :
      <vue-mathjax :formula="fractionSimple" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      etape: 0,
      racine: "$ x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}. $ ",
      proba: "$ P_A(B) = \\frac{P(A \\cap B)}{ P(A)} $",
      fractionSimple: "$ \\frac{1}{2} $",
    };
  },
};
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

Comment: Could you provide some detail on your change, other people might learn from this :)

Comment: Oh, yes of course. I avoided writing the expression directly in the template and defined, in the zone <script> , data (for example : 
data() {
         return {
              proba: '$ P_A(B) = \\frac{P(A \\cap B)}{ P(A)} $',
            SimpleFraction: "$ \\frac{1}{2} $"
}

on the other hand I display, in the <template> arré , using: <vue-mathjax:formula="proba" />
In this way, the expression is interpreted even in a two-step display.
[link]https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-mathjax-demo-forked-1u9hyi?file=/src/App.vue[/link]